# Does this motor have a gearbox inside?

Tags: motor, rpm, tachometer

I have a DC motor and the sticker says its rated for 24Vdc and 3700rpm.

There is an AC tacho inside it which I am using to measure the speed of the motor.

So when I run the motor with a 24Vdc supply and measure the AC tacho output I get a frequency of around 900Hz. So I am correct in assuming there is a gearbox inside the motor that is speeding the tacho up?

And if so, is it accurate enough to calculate the gearbox ratio based on the motor speed and AC tacho frequency? I want to use it to calculate the motor speed?

Would appreciate any help, thanks everyone.!

[image][image][image][image]

**EDIT**

See image of oscilloscope with motor running full speed and no load

Comment: Doudtful.  To get an answer, most of the following should be provided: Picture of motor.  Sticker.  Manufacturer.  Part number.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat I have added pictures to question

Comment: More likely the tacho has 14 or 16 poles and thus produces AC at 7 or 8 times the frequency a 2-pole tacho would.

Comment: Never thought of that, yeah you’re probably right. But could I take the ratio of the AC tacho frequency and dc motor frequency to get an equivalent conversion ratio  for calculating speed. The AC tacho frequency should be directly proportional to speed right?

Comment: the end cover may be easy to slide off

Comment: I found a data sheet on eBay for the motor. What does it mean when it says 1.5v / 1000rpm @ 200Hz?

Comment: I think they are telling you that both the amplitude and frequency vary with speed. So 1000 rpm / 1.5V = 666.7 rpm/volt. At 2000 rpm it will be 3V, etc. Also, 1000 rpm / 200 Hz = 5rpm / Hz. In other words, the tach signal goes through 12 cycles every rotation. (200 * 60 / 1000 = 12).

Comment: @mkeith ah ok I understand now. Thanks everyone for their help

Comment: @mkeith So basically for every rotation of the motor, the tacho will do 12 cycles, or generate 12 output pulses?

Comment: Yes. I don't know if it is some kind of roughly sinusoidal waveform or more like discrete pulses, but whatever, I believe there will be 12 full cycles per revolution. Also, looking at the data you provided, it seems the no-load speed is roughly 4182 RPM. So the tach frequency should be 836 Hz (roughly). You said it was "about 900 Hz" so that is consistent. We don't know if the no-load speed will be exactly 4182 for every motor. There is probably some variation. And "about 900" is not very precise.

Comment: @mkeith See image of AC waveform. I have a circuit that converts the positive half of that AC waveform to a square wave

Comment: 900 Hz implies 4500 RPM. (60 * 900 / 12). That definitely looks like a sine wave. I am not sure if the 1.5V at 1000 RPM is Vpeak, or Vrms or what. But if you run the motor at lower RPM's (lower voltages), you can maybe just see if the amplitude scales linearly with the frequency, if that is something you are interested in. Otherwise just use the frequency.

Comment: If you expect to play with motors frequently, I would recommend that you get a low-cost optical tachometer from Amazon or some other source. It can help confirm RPM if there is any doubt or when you can't find a datasheet for the encoder (tachometer).

Comment: Just purchased an optical tachometer, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it definitely does not have a gearbox. From other pictures I've found it appears that the tacho is implemented as an extra magnetic disk on the back of the motor that is picked up by the tacho coil. This disk has 12 sets of magnetic poles on it, so for every rotation of the motor shaft 12 pulses will be generated.

So when the motor turns at 1000RPM this corresponds to (1000/60)=16.67 rotations/second of the shaft, and multiplying this by the number of poles on the encoder disk (12) this gives you a 200Hz output signal at that speed.

Note it is highly unlikely that a motor that size actually has 12 rotor poles. It will be either 2 or 4.

Comment: Well, that style of can motor is only going to have 2 or 4.  There's brushless model airplane motors that are significantly smaller than that which have 8 or more poles.  But it's a significantly different market than a can motor.

Comment: Most likely the voltage of the tach signal is also proportional to speed. This creates the opportunity for measuring speed using voltage (if you rectify it and feed it to an ADC). Don't take my word for it, though. Test it out to make sure it works.